# C++ массив функций с разным количеством аргументов

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, vector

я новичок в программировании, а плюсы только начал учить, сильно не бейте.

Пытаюсь сделать функцию “menu” у которой 2 аргумента:

1. Массив (функций / указателей на функции)
2. Массив строк (названия этих функций)

Дошел до такого вида:

```
std::vector <std::function<void()>> VectorFunctoins = { f1,    f2,    f3    };
std::vector <std::string/*******/> VectorNameString = {"one", "two", "three"};
menu(VectorFunctoins, VectorNameString);
```

Но, оно работает только если у функций (f1, f2, f3) нет аргументов, или их количество одинаковое.

Если я дам функции аргумент ( f3(N) ), то будут ошибки:

1. C2440 инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "initializer list" в "std::vector<std::function<void (void)>,std::allocator<std::function<void (void)>>>"
2. Е0289 отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector [с _Ty=std::function<void ()>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::function<void ()>>]", соответствующие списку аргументов

Я понимаю, что массив должен содержать элементы одного типа, но можно ли сделать так чтобы оно работало с разным количеством аргументов (и разными типами этих аргументов)?

Сам код:

```
#include<iostream>

void f1()
{
    std::cout << "f1\n";
}

void f2()
{
    std::cout << "f2\n";
//  return 1;
}

void f3(int a)
{
    std::cout << "f3\n";
//  return 1;
}


#include"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\University\Laboratory work\ОС,ООП\menu\menu.h"
int main()
{
    int N = 1;

    std::vector <std::function<void()>> VectorFunctoins = {f1,     f2,    f3(N)};
    std::vector <std::string/*******/> VectorNameString = {"one", "two", "three"};
    menu(VectorFunctoins, VectorNameString);
}
```

Код файла “menu.h”:

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<functional>


void menu(std::vector <std::function<void()>> Vector_Functions,
          std::vector <std::string/********/> Vector_Function_Names)
{
    int choose = 0;
    do
    {
        system("cls");  
        std::cout << "Choose: " << "\n";
        std::cout << "0)Exit: " << "\n";
        std::cout               << "\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < Vector_Function_Names.size(); i++)
        {   std::cout << i + 1 << ")" << Vector_Function_Names[i] << "\n";   }

        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "input: ";
        std::cin >> choose;
        system("cls");

        if (choose != 0)
        {   Vector_Functions[choose - 1](); system("pause");   };

    } while (choose != 0);  std::cout << "Bye!..." << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Всегда интересно... Вот сделали вы массив функций с разными типами и количествами элементов. Как вы будете им пользоваться? Что именно и в каком количестве и как передавать `Vector_Functions[n](...)`, где `n` определится при выполнении?...

Comment: @Harry Я буду использовать его просто как меню для подпрограмм, до этого я каждый раз в main() писал его через case и выходило на ~60 строк, а теперь 3 строчки и 1 подключенный файл.

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете? Что такое _меню для подпрограмм_?

Comment: Еще раз и медленно, как для депутата, и предельно конкретно, без абстрактного. У вас есть массив `funcs` из двух элементов. В первом элементе функция без параметров, во втором — с параметром `int`. Как вы напишете вызов `funcs[n](XXXXX)`? Что будет стоять на месте `XXXXX`?

Comment: @harry я поэтому и спрашиваю, можно ли так сделать и если можно, то как. Но думаю, что вызов будет каким-то таким: 
1)`funcs[1]();`
2)`funcs[2](N);`
3)`funcs[3](A, B, ”C”);`

Comment: Если в каждой точке вызова номер элемента известен в compile-time, то используйте tuple. Но написать цикл по элементам такого контейнера (или взять элемент по индексу) будет невозможною.

Comment: @user207200 У меня есть какое-то количество независимых друг от друга функций, и я делаю консольное меню для их вызова. Допустим функции f1, f2, f3, …  при запуске программы я выбираю любую из них, а после ее выполнения возвращаюсь в меню, можно сделать его через case но каждый раз его писать не хочется

Comment: Сделайте отдельную функцию, выполняющую диспечерезацию посредством case.

Comment: Вам нужен `std::vector <std::function<void()>>`. Если при вызове нужно передать значения каких-то локальных переменных, связываете ссылки на них в лямбду, в точке инициализации вектора: ` VectorFunctoins = { f1, [&N](){ f2(N);}, [&A,&B](){ f3(A,B,"C");} };`

Comment: Harry правильно говорит, вы сами не понимаете что просите. *"Но думаю, что вызов будет каким-то таким: 1)`funcs[1]();` 2)`funcs[2](N);` 3)`funcs[3](A, B, ”C”);`"* А где вы собираетесь брать аргументы, кроме как в одном толстенном `switch`-е, от которого вы как раз пытаетесь избавиться?

Comment: @Chorkov Спасибо ваш ответ помог

Comment: сделать можно если завернуть параметры функций в один универсальный контейнер ("сообщение"). В таком случае функция будет скорее колбэкмом (callback)

Answer (score 0):

Естественно в массив нельзя положить разные типы по определению. Список аргументов функции является частью ее типа.

Но вот если передаваемые функции аргументы можно описать одним типом, тогда у вас получится вариант шаблона "Callback". Сам аргумент функции будет "сообщением" (Message).  Message может быть

1. каким-то базовым классом для всех видов сообщений или
2. гибким контейнером данных, вроде protobuf, или
3. индексом в каком-то глобальном хранилище, из которого которому функция может
   достать данные (кэш запросов\сообщений), что является частной формой реализации protobuf.

Answer (score -1):

В итоге получилось меню которое принимает на 1й аргумент массив из функций с любым количеством и типом параметров, а на 2й массив названий для этих функций

Программа:

```
#include<iostream>

void f1()
{
    std::cout << "f1" << "\n";
}

bool f2(int i, float f, char c1, char c2)
{
    std::cout << "f2" << "\n";
    std::cout << "int   i - " << i << "\n";
    std::cout << "float f - " << f << "\n";
    std::cout << "char c1 - " << c1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "char c2 - " << c2 << "\n";
    
    return true;
}


#include"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\University\Laboratory work\ОС,ООП\menu\menu.h"

int main()
{
    int   I = 1;
    float F = 2.2;
    char  C = '1';


    std::vector <std::function<void()>> VectorFunctoins = {f1,    [&I, &F, &C]() {f2(I, F, C, '2'); }};
    std::vector <std::string/*******/> VectorNameString = {"one", "two",                             };
    menu(VectorFunctoins, VectorNameString);
}
```

[image: меню]
[image: 1я функция 'f1']
[image: 2я функция 'f2']

Само меню:

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<functional>



void menu(std::vector <std::function<void()>> Vector_Functions,
          std::vector <std::string/********/> Vector_Function_Names)
{
    int choose = 0;
    do
    {
        system("cls");  
        std::cout << "Choose: " << "\n";
        std::cout << "0)Exit: " << "\n";
        std::cout               << "\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < Vector_Function_Names.size(); i++)
        {   std::cout << i + 1 << ")" << Vector_Function_Names[i] << "\n";   }

        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "input: ";
        std::cin >> choose;
        system("cls");

        if (choose != 0)
        {   Vector_Functions[choose - 1](); system("pause");   };

    } while (choose != 0);  std::cout << "Bye!..." << "\n";
}
```

Comment: И вы ровно ничего не выиграли... С тем же успехом можно писать функции `void(*)(void)`, использующие глобальные переменные.

Comment: @ Вы имеете в виду использовать функции с переменным числом параметров? Но если у параметров будут разные типы то на плюсах доставать их те еще танцы с бубном. А у меня в массиве у 1й функции нет параметров, у второй их 4 (и с разными типами этих параметров) и тд., и все прекрасно работает

Comment: Я не так понял и не на то ответил), а использовать функции с глобальными переменными неудобно, я их для этого и пишу, чтобы они были независимы и не связанны. И дальше у меня эта функция 'menu' реализуется в отдельном файле 'menu.h',  где нету этих глобальных переменных. А в моем варианте все работает без них

Comment: Чем *принципиально* отличаются от глобальных ваши `I`,`F`,`C`?

Comment: Поигрался с кодом и вы правы, смысла от передачи параметров не много...